# XML schema creation takes long time

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have the following code:

```
public XsdValidator(Resource... xsds) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(xsds != null);
    try {
      this.xsds = ImmutableList.copyOf(xsds);
      SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
      LOGGER.debug("Schema factory created: {}",schemaFactory);
      StreamSource[] streamSources = streamSourcesOf(xsds);
      LOGGER.debug("StreamSource[] created: {}",streamSources);
      Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(streamSources);
      LOGGER.debug("Schema created: {}",schema);
      validator = schema.newValidator();
      LOGGER.debug("Validator created: {}",validator);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't build XsdValidator",e);
    }
  }
```

It seems the line `schemaFactory.newSchema(streamSources);` takes a very long time (30 seconds) to execute against my XSD file.

After many tests on this XSD, it seems it's because I have:

```
  <xs:complexType name="entriesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="prov:entryType" name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10000" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

The problem is `maxOccurs="10000"`

With `maxOccurs="1"` or `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, it is very fast.

Can someone tell me what's the problem of using `maxOccurs="10000"` ?

Comment: Can you please try using maxOccurs="unbounded"? What do you get in your case?

Comment: The result for unbounded is already in my question @PetruGardea : it's fast

Comment: Somehow I've missed that... It means that it is trying to allocate memory (most likely). I would run a performance profiler, just to confirm.

Comment: perhaps, but my question is why? not what :)

Comment: Hmm... you've asked "what's the problem of using"... hence the what. As far as why, I've used to run into [this problem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296034). I am sure that if you narrow search terms to match your particular setup, you'll find out more...

Comment: thanks, I would accept that link as an answer

Comment: Link to xerces bug : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my personal experience, having particles bounded by what some may consider "unreasonably" high values is cause for performance problems ([this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296034) is from my browser's favourites).

The underlying cause seems to be memory allocation (to the effect indicated by the maxOccurs value).

Also, I recall a documentation item which was stating a threshold value beyond which, for all intents and purposes, the parser would actually treat the maxOccurs as unbounded, regardless of what the XSD says (I'll revisit this post if I find it).

Comment: The link you provided is only a RAD (Eclipse) performance issue and not an application performance problem... right? @Petru Gardea

Comment: @javaPlease42, not really, if you go through it, you may notice that it is a Xerces problem; some people reported that it is still manifesting in 2.11 (I cannot confirm that).